# C++: Using map to sort and print the value of a string occurrences in a text file

Tags: c++, sorting, dictionary, priority-queue

Okay guys, I am trying to teach myself how to use map. My intentions are to open a txt file and count all of those words and then show how many times that the specific word occurs. Then (IF ITS POSSIBLE) I would like to use that first map in a second map to call those values and only output the top 10 (or 20 or whatever) frequent words that occurs and print the number of times (from largest to smallest) that it occurs, along with the actual word.

I have already figured out how to output ALL the words and how many times they occur. And I think its pretty cool that map already sorts the actual strings that I called within it automatically. My problem is just that I need those values sorted, not the strings.

I've made comments on the specific functionalities of the code but I am just not sure about this other map.

I am only seeking different ideas. Please don't be mean.

**Someone mentioned to me about a priority_queue but that is also new to me. If you could explain this also in a more verbal way with an example so that I can understand, that would be great!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//makes word count a declaration 
//makes count word a declaration 
typedef map <string, int> word_count;
typedef map <int, string> count_word; 


int main()
{
word_count word_count;
string filename;


// Get the filename.
cout << "enter data.txt ";
cin >> filename;

// Open file.
ifstream file(filename.c_str());

// Read in all the words.
string word;
while (file >> word)
{
    // Remove punctuation.
    int index;
    while ((index = word.find_first_of(".,!?\\;-*+[]<>() '")) != string::npos)
    {
        word.erase(index, 1);
    }

    ++word_count[word];
 }


 std::map <int, string> count_word;

 // Print out the first 10 words counts.
 word_count::const_iterator current(word_count.begin());


 int count = 0;
 while (current != word_count.end() && count<10)
 {

    count++;
    cout << "The word '" << current->first << "'      appears " << current->second << " times" << endl;
    count_word.insert(std::pair<int, string>(current->second, current->first));
    ++current;

 }


 count_word::const_iterator new_current(count_word.begin());
 count = 0;

while (new_current != count_word.end() && count<10)
{

     count++;
    cout << new_current -> first <<  " times    appears the word '" <<
            current -> second <<  endl;
     ++new_current;
}

 system("pause");
  }
```

Comment: I think this approach complicates your life :) you could have the map int -> string, but then how do you deal with ties ? If two words have same number, they'd override each other; you can have a map <int, set<string>> , and add to the set, but then your code becomes more complicated (which it needs to be, since with ties, there may be 11 words with same frequency, so there are no top 10). A priority queue makes sense, or just a vector of <word,freq> and sort by freq ...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new map container  as follow

```
std:map<int,string> count_word
```

and insert pair from the already existing map to this. The new map will sort itself as you want.

Here the code snippet.I didn't compile.

```
std:map<int,string> count_word;
word_count::const_iterator current(word_count.begin());


int count = 0;
while (current != word_count.end() && count<10)
{

    count++;
    cout << "The word '" << current -> first << "'      appears " << current -> second << " times" << endl;
    count_word.insert(std::pair<int,string>(current->second,current->first);
    ++current;

}

count_word::const_iterator new_current(count_word.begin());
//for(auto &x:count_word)
//std::cout<<x->first<<"no of times"<< x->second << "word"<<endl;
//Either you can use above 2 line to print or below given few lines 
while (new_current != word_count.end() && count<10)
{

     count++;
    cout << new_current -> first <<  " times    appears the word '" <<<< current -> second <<  endl;
     ++new_current;
}
```

Comment: See logically I thought about this, only didn't know exactly how to use it to sort by values after that map is declared.

Comment: So, I compiled the snippet two different times using the two different while statements and its only sorting the words. I understand that map automatically does this. What if the values of those words could be sorted. <hr/> Example "Zeta" appears "18" times <hr/> "Tau" appears "12" times <hr/> "Gamma" appears "9" times..... etc

Comment: map contains <key,value> pair. value of the first map is the key of the second map. std::map only sort on key. please update code with your latest change.

Comment: Add last while loop  block from my code snippet before system("pause");

Comment: When I initially tried that, the last while statement wont let != work.

Answer (score 0):

A [priority queue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/) allows setting a custom comparator which you can use to your advantage, by comparing the counts (map values) your queue can be sorted by value (`map` can also use a comparator but it only works on the keys):

```
typedef pair<string,int> str_to_int; // = word_count::value_type
struct Compare {
    bool operator()(const str_to_int & a, const str_to_int & b) {
        return a.second < b.second;
    }
};
// ...
priority_queue<str_to_int, vector<str_to_int>, Compare> queue(word_count.begin(), word_count.end());
// Print the top 10
for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
    const str_to_int & e = queue.top();
    queue.pop();
    cout << "The word '" << e.first << "'      appears " << e.second << " times" << endl;
}
```